# Writing to a file in python

Tags: python, encryption, writetofile

The following is the code

```
import sys
print "Enter '1' to upload a file." +'\n'
print "Enter '2' to download a file." +'\n'
print "Enter '3' to view the contents of a file" +'\n'
print "Enter '4' to delete the file" +'\n'
print "Enter '0' to exit"

class switch(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.fall = False

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return the match method once, then stop"""
        yield self.match
        raise StopIteration

    def match(self, *args):
        """Indicate whether or not to enter a case suite"""
        if self.fall or not args:
            return True
        elif self.value in args: # changed for v1.5, see below
            self.fall = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

import swiftclient
auth_url =  "https://identity.open.softlayer.com"+"/v3"
project_id = "307dc262d1e548848fa0207e217d0b16"
user_id = "7cb8aa19292c41d7a14709f428a5e8ff"
region_name = "dallas"
conn = swiftclient.Connection(key="B1.~QWR4rXG?!n,_",
authurl=auth_url,
auth_version='3',
os_options={"project_id": project_id,
"user_id": user_id,
"region_name": region_name})
container_name = 'new-container'

# File name for testing
file_name = 'example_file.txt'

# Create a new container
conn.put_container(container_name)
print "nContainer %s created successfully." % container_name

# List your containers
print ("nContainer List:")
for container in conn.get_account()[1]:
    print container['name']
# Create a file for uploading
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
#print "asasa",cipher_suite

f=open("local.txt",'r')
content=f.read()
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(content)
print cipher_text
d=open("sample.txt",'w')
d.write(cipher_text)

while(1):
    v=raw_input("enter your input")


    for case in switch(v):

        if case('1'):
            print "upload a file"
            with open("sample.txt", 'r') as example_file:
                conn.put_object(container_name,
                file_name,
                contents= example_file.read(),
                content_type='text/plain')
                print "file uploaded successfully"
            break
        if case('2'):
            print "download a file"
            obj = conn.get_object(container_name, file_name)
            with open(file_name, 'w') as my_example:
                my_example.write(obj[1])
                print "nObject %s downloaded successfully." % file_name
            break
        if case('3'):

            print ("nObject List:")
            for container in conn.get_account()[1]:
                for data in conn.get_container(container['name'])[1]:
                    print 'object: {0}t size: {1}t date: {2}'.format(data['name'], data['bytes'], data['last_modified'])
            break
        if case('4'):
            print delete
            conn.delete_object(container_name, file_name)
            print "nObject %s deleted successfully." % file_name
            conn.delete_container(container_name)
            print "nContainer %s deleted successfully.n" % container_name

            break
        if case('0'):
            exit(0)
            break
        if case(): # default, could also just omit condition or 'if True'
            print "something else!"
```

Under create a file for uploading section I have tried to create two files. The second file is for storing the ciphertext so that I could pass it in the 1st switch case.But writing to the second file isn't happening.However if I copy and paste the following segment of a code in a new Python file and try executing it, it is working fine.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
#print "asasa",cipher_suite
f=open("local.txt",'r')
content=f.read()
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(content)
print cipher_text
d=open("sample.txt",'w')
d.write(cipher_text)
```

The encrypted text is being written to the sample.txt.

I don't understand why it isn't working in the first case, but is working in the second.

Comment: you don't have to `raise StopIteration` manually, that is done automatically at the end of any generator. Also the recommended practice is to put all yours imports at the top of your code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to read from the same file: `with open("sample.txt", 'r') as example_file`. So please close it before.

```
d=open("sample.txt", 'w')
d.write(cipher_text)
d.close()
```

Or

```
with open("sample.txt", 'w') as d:
    d.write(cipher_text)
```

BTW, if you want to see the content in a file right after you wrote, you have to flush it:

```
d=open("sample.txt", 'w')
d.write(cipher_text)
d.flush()
while(1):
    v=raw_input("enter your input")
```

Right after `d.flush()` you can inspect your file from a separate terminal. But again, in your case it would be better to `close()` it.